# Remember component state after returning from frame change?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a frame on the main timeline with many components such as comboboxes, steppers and dynamic/input textboxes.

After going to another frame and then later back to this frame, the components reset to how they were initially.

Is there a way to have it remember the state it is being left in, so it can return to the same state when going back?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a frame extend over every frame and have individual key frames in another layer like so:

[image]

and just leave the extended frame empty but hold variables to tell a MovieClip what frame it should go to when it is loaded again.. or any other values

e.g.

```
var MovieClip1Frame:int = 1; // in the extended frame
```

then

```
MovieClip1.gotoAndStop(MovieClip1Frame); // in the frame the MovieClip is held
```

then just each time you leave the frame update the variable like:

```
MovieClip1Frame = MovieClip1.currentFrame();
```

Not sure how efficient that is but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should read answers more thoroughly. As I already said, *when you need to do a quantity of similar operations it is always **loop**.* If the objects you work with are not exactly similar, you are responsible to find a way in which they are similar and make a use of it.

```
// *** BEGINNING OF INITIALIZATION *** //

var Store:Object;

// First, you need to figure, if you are entering
// the frame for the first time or not.
if (Store)
{
    // Object is initialized, it's second time.

    processAll(restoreOne);
}
else
{
    Store = new Object;

    // Store the initial values.
    processAll(storeOne);
}

// Subscribe all components to the CHANGE event.
processAll(subscribeOne);

// *** END OF INITIALIZATION *** //

// This function loops through all the display children
// and applies a given method to each one of them.
function processAll(processOne:Function):void
{
    // Backward loop is faster than forward because of condition.
    // Comparing iterator to fixed number is faster than to variable.
    // Not that you would notice any performance boost, but still.
    for (var i:int = numChildren - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        // Get the reference to the child object.
        var aChild:DisplayObject = getChildAt(i);

        // Apply the given method to the child.
        processOne(aChild);
    }
}

// Subscribes one target to CHANGE event.
// I cannot guarantee they all dispatch it and
// not some other event, HAVE IT AS A GUIDELINE.
function subscribeOne(target:DisplayObject):void
{
    // Figure if it is one of your components.
    if (aChild is NumericStepper)
    {
        aChild.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onChange);
    }
    else if (aChild is ComboBox)
    {
        aChild.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onChange);
    }
    else if (aChild is TextInput)
    {
        aChild.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onChange);
    }

    // And so on, for every component type you have.
}

// Every standard component dispatches CHANGE event
// that indicates the component's state/value was changed.
function onChange(e:Event):void
{
    // Store the changed value of the component
    // that dispatched the CHANGE event.
    storeOne(e.target as DisplayObject);
}

// Stores the value/state of a given component.
function storeOne(target:DisplayObject):void
{
    // As there are different components, you should
    // differ the ways you record their states/values.
    if (target is NumericStepper)
    {
        Store[target.name] = (target as NumericStepper).value;
    }
    else if (target is ComboBox)
    {
        Store[target.name] = (target as ComboBox).selectedIndex;
    }
    else if (target is TextInput)
    {
        Store[target.name] = (target as TextInput).text;
    }

    // And so on, for every component type you have.
}

// Restores value/state of a given component.
function restoreOne(target:DisplayObject):void
{
    // Get the reference to the child object.
    var aChild:DisplayObject = getChildAt(i);

    // Figure if it is one of your components.
    if (aChild is NumericStepper)
    {
        (aChild as NumericStepper).value = Store[aChild.name];
    }
    else if (aChild is ComboBox)
    {
        (aChild as ComboBox).selectedIndex = Store[aChild.name];
    }
    else if (aChild is TextInput)
    {
        (aChild as TextInput).text = Store[aChild.name];
    }

    // And so on, for every component type you have.
}
```

One more thing to heed. Some components are not initialized right away and take one extra frame to get ready. In this case they can **NOT** accept the stored values until the next frame.